# Record screen activity with SharpAvi

Tags: c#, wpf, video-capture

I've got an issue while recording screen activity with SharpAvi, here is my code :

```
    SharpAvi.Output.AviWriter aviW = new SharpAvi.Output.AviWriter(videoRecorderFileLocation);
    SharpAvi.Output.IAviVideoStream streamAVI = aviW.AddVideoStream(500, 300, SharpAvi.BitsPerPixel.Bpp32);
    streamAVI.Codec = SharpAvi.KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MicrosoftMpeg4V3;
```

On a timer, every 40 ms I record an image like this :

```
        System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 300, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(image);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(500, 300), System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            streamAVI.WriteFrame(true, // is key frame? (many codecs use concept of key frames, for others - all frames are keys)
                  ms.ToArray(), // array with frame data
                  0, // starting index in the array
                  ms.ToArray().Length // length of the data
            );
        }

        videoRecorderTimer.Start();
```

And I close the video with

```
        videoRecorderTimer.Stop();
        aviW.Close();
```

The video file is correctly created, but it has no images in it (or has black images) when I read it with VLC.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I created a desktop recorder and I had the same issue, it was fixed when I called .Dispose();

Comment: I used MEE4 (Microsoft Expression Encoder 4) pulled all the .dll I needed and then made the process at the end of the encoding I called job.Dispose(); instead of job.Close(); it fixed my problem.. However I have never used the one your using. It should be similar though.

Comment: I added a codec choice, but now I get a gray screen instead of a black one. There is no Dispose() function on the AviWriter or on the VideoStream.